# Configure command line look in Vim

Tags: vim

Is it possible to change the default Vim command line look when you are in some buffer to see some valuable information? How?
What Vim help page corresponds to these options?

Comment: You Might want to migrate to: http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Bobthezealot "Warning: this site is currently in private beta for at least 2 more days. [...]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you can't get Vim to do exactly what you want, but you can get close.  Read:

```
:help 'laststatus'
:help 'statusline'
```

(The single-quotes are meant to be typed as part of the help command.)

Specifically, you want to make the statusline always show up:

```
:set laststatus=2
```

Then configure the statusline with the appropriate formatting characters.  Remember to escape your spaces in the option's value with a backslash.  I can't provide an example since you did not indicate what you want displayed.

Comment: You understood me wrong I do not talk about status line I am talking about command line. I am curious is there some kind of configuration of information it displays, for example, something like there is for status line.

Comment: No, it looks like I understood you correctly. I said you cannot do what you want. Then I offered an alternative.